# Distinct or Union is selecting duplicate data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, union, distinct

I have a table with 526 rows and has lot of duplicate data. For removing duplicate I used this script:

```
select distinct fullname, RegistrationNumber
from tbllookupStudentInfo1;
```

I got 291 rows, but it still has duplicate column so I tried using union:

```
select distinct fullname, RegistrationNumber
from tbllookupStudentInfo1
union 
select fullname,RegistrationNumber
from tbllookupStudentInfo1;
```

I got 291 rows, but still I am getting few duplicate value. And then I select just Fullname using both union and distinct and got 213 rows which consists few duplicate fullname too. How should I solve this?

[image]

Comment: In the image that you posted it is obvious that some values in RegistrationNumber contain a leading space.

Comment: Try: `select distinct fullname, ltrim(rtrim(RegistrationNumber))....` (or: `select distinct fullname, trim(RegistrationNumber)....`  on SQL Server **2017** and newer) and you should be fine

Comment: So 1st i should remove blank spaces.

Comment: If it's only leading spaces you need to trim, you could use `LTRIM`, which will work on older versions too: `UPDATE tbllookupStudentInfo1 SET RegistrationNumber = LTRIM(RegistrationNumber);`

Comment: I did this :
   SET RegistrationNumber = LTRIM(RegistrationNumber);
   UPDATE tbllookupStudentInfo1 
   SET FullName = LTRIM(FullName);
  
   UPDATE tbllookupStudentInfo1 
   SET FullName = RTRIM(FullName);

Ltrim work but not Rtrim in my Sql server 2014. I could not remove tail space